# ArcMap: compare overlapping partially transparent rasters using swipe tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.4, swipe

I'd like two compare two rasters in ArcMap 10.4. I can do this using the Swipe tool on the Effects toolbar, however, this only allows me to interactively drag the top layer over the bottom one (top and bottom referring to their order in the table of contents). Since my NoData cells are transparent and their location differs between the rasters, the bottom layer 'shines through' the top layer which makes comparison difficult.

I can solve the issue by setting the NoData-value in both rasters to a non-transparent colour that contrasts with the colour scale, but I'd rather keep it transparent.

Another option would be to use different colour scales for each raster to spot where the bottom one shines through, however, I find using the same colour scales better for honest comparison.

When using swipe (or a similar tool) I would like to show the top layer instead of the bottom layer, rather than showing it on top. Does anybody know whether this is a possibility? Is there a way I can select both layers and use 'swipe' to show either of them, but never both?